# Connecting r with Hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop

I am trying to integrate r with hadoop using Revolution Analytics RHadoop
BUt i am facing problems using windows.
I am gettting error while running rmr package

```
Error in mr(map = map, reduce = reduce, reduce.on.data.frame = reduce.on.data.frame, :
  hadoop streaming failed with error code 127
```

Has anyone any idea how this issue can be resolved

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using? 0.20.2 version of StreamJob.java doesn't return 127 as an error code (just 1-5). Are there any more error messages / logs you can share? (There must be output of the client somewhere)

Comment: i am using 0.20.2 but when i run mapreduce function in R-13.1 after loading rmr package i get same error as show above

Comment: You may be interested in this webcast from this week: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=QEaOfTuveGg#!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use CDH3 or higher or Apache Hadoop 1.0.2 or higher. If you absolutely have to run it with 0.20.2 there is a list of patches you need to apply on the wiki (Which Hadoop for rmr). Have you just asked on the issue tracker by any chance? Unfortunately there are many forums you can use, but only one answer.